# How to pass Authentication header from one soap request to another soap request in SnapLogic

Tags: soap, snaplogic

I am newbie in snaplogic.

I have an Soap API which has two methods authenticate(username,password) which authenticate the user and then I have some x() which do some work.

I am PHP Developer, The code works fine when I use SoapClient library in PHP. By first calling the authenticate and then x.

But In Snaplogic, My first request works fine i.e. authenticate. But in the second request it says you need to be authenticated. I have combined the whole calls. I have passed the cookie of the first call to other.

By writing in http header

cookie : value is previous request set-cookie.

Anyone can figure out, where am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Unlike some other tools, you don't need to do a separate authentication call first to make your main SOAP call. In SnapLogic, you have to set up an account corresponding to the snap you are using and authentication will be handled by it.

In your case, it will be a **SOAP Basic Auth** account. After creating it, you then need to configure this account in your **SOAP Execute** snap (through the Account tab).